# what is the best way to get data from nodejs server and send data to angular generated page?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am new to nodejs+angular app. I just want to pass some data from node server to pages generated by angular. How can I do that? is there something like,

```
response.render('URL',JSONDATA);
```

using which I am able to get data to a specified URL. Just for information I am using ng-view/ ng-route on my UI pages for fast loading.

On Client side:

```
app.config([ '$locationProvider','$routeProvider', function($locationProvider,$routeProvider) {
//$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'src/pages/login.html'
}).when('/new-enquiry', {
    templateUrl : 'src/pages/enq-form.html'
}).when('/dashboard', {
    templateUrl : 'src/pages/dashboard.html'
}).when('/edit-enquiry', {
    templateUrl : 'src/pages/edit.html'
}).when('/all-enquiry', {
    templateUrl : 'src/pages/all-enquiry.html'
});
```

} ]);

What I have to do is for example in login page, after submitting I need to redirect to a new page and send username to that page. I dont want to use ejs and jade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the docs at

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

For example, you can configure a `controller` for every route, which then uses the `$http` service to request data from your Node.js backend. The data is rendered in the template you provide per route (such as `src/pages/login.html`).

Comment: But will it be an efficient way? that how we do it normally right?

Comment: Define "efficient"... If you want to use client-side templating with Angular, and not server-sided, how else should this work?